# Visual Studio - Reference dll library

Tags: windows-phone-8, reference, visual-studio-2013

I needed to add chart to my WP8 application and I found these nice ones:
http://modernuicharts.codeplex.com/releases/view/106190

Downloading binaries was all right, however I needed to download the source since there were some changes in order to fit it into my application. The point is that, after I made the changes, I built the dlls and I pick the one in Silverlight sub-project.

When I try to import the library into my application, it says that the assemply is not compatible or maybe it's a previous version. I didn't edit anything else apart from few lines of code.
Where is the problem?

Comment: Do you have an assembly that targets the Phone?

Comment: The assembly at your provided link does not target WP8. - No chance using it this way.

Comment: @malte try it yourself the Silverlight version

Comment: @fillobotto I'm sorry! - Overread the information. According to the site SL assembly should work as expected. Unfortunately I'm running into the same error when I try to import the self-built assembly.

Comment: @malte maybe the problem is the target Silverlight framework version? In the source project it's Silverlight 5

Comment: As far as I know, SL 5 *is* the platform for WP8 development.
Did you notice the file size differences from the downloaded and self-compiled assembly? (approx. 40kb - 150kb)

Comment: @malte I posted on their Codeplex page - Discussions section - because I'm courious to see where is the problem.

Comment: Why not try another charts library, there are several for WP8? Also, SL5 and WP8 are quite different, WP8 uses WinRT mostly, SL5 does not.

Comment: @NeilTurner I tryied many different ones, but they looked weird. Telerik's charts for instance.

Comment: Did you succeed in add reference to the project?

Comment: @verdesrobert no, then I decied to organize the UI differently and I was no longer in need of this library